# Javascript pass variable in href onclick request

Tags: javascript, variables, href

I know this is really basic javascript but for some reason, I can't seem to get my link's onclick function to work when passing a parameter.

I have tried escaping the quotes, adding different types of quotes and adding the raw variable as a string.

I have it working with the below but it says that "XYZ is undefined"

```
function renderLink(value, meta, record)
        {
            var type = record.data['name']; //value is XYZ  


            return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getReport('+type+'); return false;"></a>';
        }

function getReport(type){

    alert(type);
}
```

Comment: How are you inserting this HTML back into the DOM?

Comment: What is record.data['name'] is for ?

Comment: It's returned to an extjs grid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getReport('+type+'); return false;"></a>';
```

You need to escape the string:

```
return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getReport(\''+type+'\'); return false;"></a>';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the rendered HTML, you'll see the problem: Your `getReport` call looks like this:

```
getReport(XYZ);
```

I'm guessing you want quotes around that, so:

```
return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getReport(\''+type+'\'); return false;"></a>';
```

...which renders:

```
getReport('XYZ');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ilakaw)

Somewhat more esoteric, but when you output an `onclick` attribute as part of HTML source, it is of course an HTML attribute, which means you can use character entities. So you *could* use the `&quot;` entity:

```
return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getReport(&quot;'+type+'&quot;); return false;"></a>';
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ilakaw/2)

I point this out not because I recommend it (I don't), but because it's useful to remember what's really going on in an `onclick` attribute. This is one of the reasons I would strongly recommend using a proper event handler (e.g., via `addEventListener` / `attachEvent`, or even just assigning to the `a` element's `onclick` property once it's been instantiated) instead.

---

It's important to note that this way of doing it is also very sensitive to the *content* of `record.data['name']`. For instance, consider what happens if instead of `XYZ` it's `Tom's`. The output of the first option above would be

```
getReport('Tom's');
```

...which is obviously a problem. Similarly, if there's a backslash in the text, it will be treated as an escape character on the result, etc., etc. — a bit of a minefield.

If you can possibly change your `renderLink` so it returns an actual instantiated `a` element rather than a string, that's what I'd do:

```
function createLink(value, meta, record)
{
    var type = record.data['name'];         // Grab value as of when we were called
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = "javascript:void(0);";
    link.onclick = function() {             // Or even better, addEventListener / attachEvent
        getReport(type);
        return false;
    };

    return link;
}
```

That creates the link and a *closure* that accesses `type` without turning it into text and back again. (Don't worry if you're unfamiliar with closures, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).)

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ilakaw/3)

Answer (score 0):

getReport receives XYZ as a variable not as a string, you need to put that inside quotes:

```
return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getReport(\''+type+'\'); return false;"></a>';
```